# Why wont my song variable equal input when its been previously used

Tags: python

I'm creating this code as a little challenge for myself and am stumped.
My task is to create a song quiz where you are given the Artist's name and the first letter of his song and have to guess it. The songs and artists are extracted from a CSV file.
My song variable is called displaying only the first letter and the player has to guess the song title. After the Song letter has been shown if the input matches the song it doesn't show a "correct" message.

I've previously given thought to whether instead of saying 'if input == song' say 'if input in line' however I found if you used any letter in that line of the file it would be accepted.

File:

```
Artist,Song   
NSG,Options   
Jamie,Streatham   
Dave,Location
```

```py
def Newgame():  
    global Score  
    with open("songs") as songs_file:  
        Lines = songs_file.readlines()  
        Score = 0  
        Lives = 2  
        while Lives > 0:  
            Lives = 2  
            Artist_song = random.choice(Lines)  
            Artist, Song= Artist_song.split(",")  
            print(Artist +"," + Song[0])  
            Users_song = input("What is the song: ")  
            if Users_song == Song:  
                print("Well done")  
                Score = Score + 3  
            else:  
                Lives = Lives - 1  
                print("Wrong, try again")
```

when the input matches the song from the file I want to see well done but instead see incorrect for some unknown reason

Comment: Why are you printing `Song[0]` and not `Song`?

Comment: Quick side-note: you're setting Lives = 2 at the beginning of your loop, which means that your lives will always be reset every guess. Not sure if this is intentional for testing purposes or something.

Comment: @bozdoz He specified in the question that the question only gives the first letter of the Song, and the user has to guess from there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your current code doesn't do anything, as you never call the function.  Also, stick in `print` statements to show the variable values.

Comment: @bozdoz I am printing the first letter so that the player has to guess the remainder of thes song.

Comment: @Ahndwoo theres more to this loop but this is all that is necessary.

Comment: Check your input and file lines: does one have an EOL character, where the other does not?  `strip` will fix that for you.

Comment: @LeightstaDB could it be a case-sensitivity problem? Or maybe there's whitespace after the song name? You could try this to account for some of those issues: `if Users_song.lower() == Song.lower().strip()`

Comment: I just ran your code and hard-coded the artist-song pairs and it worked just fine, are you reading/parsing the text file data correctly?